# Suggesting project ideas using Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, ethics, recruitment

I have an idea for a fairly simple OS X utility I want, but I don't currently know enough about OS X development to make it myself.

Someone on Stack Overflow could write it in an hour or two.

What are the ethics(?) of asking a question, with the primary intention being to getting someone to write this utility?

This happened completely inadvertently with ["Tool to determine what lowest version of Python required?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804538/tool-to-determine-what-lowest-version-of-python-required) - I asked that purely out of curiosity, to see if such an application existed. It didn't. Fair enough.. Then a few days later Greg Hewgill answered the question with a link to his Github project!

It's sort of "recruitment", but recruitment implies money and this is more a suggestion for some bored programmer.

Answer (score 3):

You have 12.4k - if it's important to you, post a question asking for it and throw in a bounty of 500.

This, however, kind of sucks as you have to wait 48 hours or whatever until you are able to attach a bounty to a question. This doesn't seem particularly logical to me as sometimes you know it's something that requires a little work and you just want to put the bounty on there from the start. 
Hell, my top question was asking people to program a [boggle solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746082/how-to-find-list-of-possible-words-from-a-letter-matrix-boggle-solver) and plenty of people threw their solutions in. I meant to add a bounty when I started the question, but the 48 hour limit made me forget about it until it was already pretty much over. I think I'll go ahead and add a bounty now...

Comment: That's a very interesting concept... using rep to get someone to write a small utility program for you.  Somehow it feels dirty, but from another view, it seems kind of reasonable...

Comment: And the bounty also protects it from being closed too, correct? You just have to keep your question alive for two days though...

Answer (score 2):

For a long time I've been wishing there was a site/organization out there that would act as a broker between open-source customers, and open-source programmers... (maybe there is one?) I have situations like this myself: there's some simple tool I really want, or a simple feature I'd love to have added to programs I use, but I don't know how to do it myself, and I can't afford to pay someone lots of $$$. But I would be willing to pay $100 or $200/yr to some organization that would award $$ to programmers who fill in the gaps for small-project software improvements that don't exist.

Comment: Have you tried ODesk?